# Store extra data in refresh token

Tags: encryption, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I am developing a web application which encrypts user data on the server. When the user logs in via forms auth I have their password and can decrypt the data.

If the user however authorizes an app via OAuth2 then the original password is only available during creation of the access and refresh token. So in this step I generate another key for the decryption of the data and store it in the access token (so I don't send the user password around and can expire this key if needed).

However, once the access token expires and the refresh token is used to create a new one, I no longer have the user password to create another key and this process breaks. Using DotNetOpenAuth I have been able to store the key in the access token but not in the refresh token.

Is it possible to store extra data in the refresh token? I can think of another way to do this where the client fetches a key from the server on first authorization with OAuth but I don't like this approach since it breaks the access flow. A client has to store this additional data securely and has to resubmit it with every request.

Comment: Did you end up finding a way to do this?

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't find any way to do it. From scouring the source code of DotNetOpenOut I figured it was not possible. I ended up implementing an extra method to get the key so the client first authorizes and then fetches the key with the token. This key is then kept on the client and is only valid for that authorization so when the token is revoked the key stops working as well.